# Driving 5 RGB LEDs using a microcontroller

Tags: pwm

I need to run 5 differnet rgb LEDs from a microcontroller. All the LEDs will be producing the same color so there will only be 3 separate PWMs (1 for each channel of rgb.) My problem is most microcontrollers can't handle this load. What's the best way to handle this?

I was wondering if there is a microcontroller chip/board that can handle 3 separate PWM's outputting from 15 pins. If possible I'd rather not have to use a PWM Driver as this would increase the complexity of my design.

Bonus points if you guys know of a board that's compact.

Answer (score 1):

A transistor or mosfet per channel, with the 5 rgb leds in parallel. That's all you need. The microcontroller drives the transistor easy enough, and the transistor drives the higher current of the leds.

Comment: And possibly ballast resistors if you don't trust the LED manufacturer.

Comment: so 3 transistors?